# Question on "walk out on someone"

Tags: grammar

Might there be a context in which **"He walked out on me"** is meant for **"He walked out to me"**, not **"He walked out from me"** ?

For example,

> While I was preparing for my daughter's birthday party, my husband was
>   doing his work in his room, and after he was done with it, he **walked
>   out on** me to help me.

(I made this sentence)

I know **"walk out on someone"** usually means **"leave someone"**, but I think that could mean different according to context, as shown above.

If my thinking about "walk out on" is right, can these expressions mean different according to context?

1. Rush out on
2. Run out on
3. Go out on
4. Move out on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never known "**to walk out on**" to mean anything but to leave. Your example does not make sense. It says "*... he left me [in order] to help me*". The sentence should read

> While I was preparing for my daughter's birthday party, my husband was doing his work in his room, and after he was done with it, he walked [came] out to help me.

Comment: If "walked out upon/onto" is used instead, would that sentence mean clear?

Comment: If you say  "... he walked out upon me..." it still means he left you. If you say "... he walked out onto me ..." it's even worse! You are saying he physically walked onto your body, presumably whilst you were lying on the floor.

Comment: However, this sentence "‎He went out on the balcony" doesn't mean "He left the balcony". So, I don't understand why "walk out on" cannot be used to express approaching someone.

Comment: In this case it is a shortened form of "_ He walked out **onto** the balcony_" and there is no suggestion that he is leaving it. I do however agree that this is an exception to what I said in my answer, but **onto** is a better way of saying it.

Comment: @SinK - "Walk out on" works, but, as Peter just said, it emphasizes what you are stepping onto, not who or what you are going toward. So, we can say any of these: _he walked out on the ledge, he walked out on the pier, we ran out on the field, they tiptoed out on the tightrope_, etc. Also worth noting: we don't need to include the "out" in any of those, although it does emphasize that the subject is venturing somewhere, as opposed to going there incidentally. I can say, "Bob walked on the street," or, "Bob walked _out_ on the street," but the latter emphasizes how Bob is leaving the sidewalk.

Comment: @J.R. Then... can "go out on someone"  be used to mean "to abandon or leave someone" as well ?

Comment: @SinK - Short ans.: No. The idiomatic phrasal verb is [walk out on](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/walk-out-on). You can't say "go out on" to mean "abandon" any more than you can use "inflate up" (instead of "blow up") to mean "explode." Longer ans.: English is a flexible language, and, with enough context, words can sometimes be shuffled and tweaked for humorous effect. It's not too hard to imagine someone saying something like, "Ted's old girlfriend was crazy! He didn't just walk out on her, he ran out on her." But those are rare exceptions that should not be overused.

Comment: @J.R. But I was able to find this example written by a native speaker on Twitter. **"The lights just went out on Trump as he was saying he has "full faith" in the country's intelligence agencies"**. Here, isn't it clear that **"went out on Trump"** means **"left Trump"** or **"abandon Trump"** ?

Comment: @SinK - No, "lights went out" means something different. It means the lights shut off – in this case, metaphorical lights.

Answer (score 3):

### The example sentence does not sound correct.

> While I was preparing for my daughter's birthday party, my husband was doing his work in his room, and after he was done with it, he walked out on me to help me.

You are right that "**walk out on someone**" means a *negative* action that can *hurt someone*:

> **to abandon**
>   -- *Farlex, [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/walk+out+on)*

or

> **to leave without finishing something**
>   -- *[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/walk-out-on-sth)*

It does not work with the idea that *he helped me*.

### To fix the example

To make sense, the example would need to be changed to something like:

> ✔️ After he was done with his work, he walked **`out of his workshop`** to help me.
>
> After he was done, he walked **`out of his room`** to help me.

This is fine grammatically — but it sounds a little strange. (You are using extra words to describe the walking.) Is this a castle that takes extra effort to walk around in?

It’s better to just get right to the point:

> ✔️ After he was done, he **came over** to help me.

## You can walk out of doors

So walking out on someone or something is usually understood to mean “abandonment.”

You can, however, walk out on the porch, walk out on a deck, walk out on the patio, or walk out on a balcony.

Here, the word out is understood to mean “going from inside to outside“, or from “indoors to outdoors“.

## walking in on someone

There’s a different phrase, “walking in on someone” or “walking in on something,” which is totally different.

There are a lot of different propositions that can be used with the word “walk“:  walk by, walk-through,  walk out on, walk in on, etc.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/walk)  has a good definition of choices.

Comment: Comments are not for extended conversation; therefore, the previous discussion has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97491/discussion-on-answer-by-whiskeychief-question-on-walk-out-on-someone).

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with, "After he was done, he came out of his room to help me."